jqassistant when scanning jar file java.lang.LinkageError
I'm using com.buschmais.jqassistant.cli-jqassistant-commandline-neo4jv4-2.1.0.jar to scan spring boot jars
This is how my .jqassistant.yml file looks:
jqassistant:
  skip: false
  plugins:
    - group-id: org.jqassistant.plugin
      artifact-id: jqassistant-spring-plugin
      version: 2.1.0-M1
    - group-id: org.jqassistant.plugin
      artifact-id: jqassistant-plantuml-report-plugin
      version: 2.0.1
  
  store:
    embedded:
      neo4j-plugins:
        - group-id: org.neo4j.procedure
          artifact-id: apoc
          version: 4.4.0.25

  scan:
    include:
      files:
        - Projects/jqassistant-springboot-project/libs/invoiceservice.jar       
    properties:
      file.exclude: /BOOT-INF/lib/**
    reset: true
    continue-on-error: true

              
  analyze:
    report:
      fail-on-severity: BLOCKER
    groups:
      - microservices

When I run the ./jqassistant/bin/jqassistant.sh scan
I get the following error:
2024-04-22 15:26:10.825 [main] INFO AbstractContainerScannerPlugin - Entering /Projects/jqassistant-springboot-project/libs/invoiceservice.jar
ANTLR Tool version 4.9.2 used for code generation does not match the current runtime version 4.7.2ANTLR Runtime version 4.9.2 used for parser compilation does not match the current runtime version 4.7.22024-04-22 15:26:10.894 [main] WARN AbstractGraphStore - Rolling back an active transaction.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation for class com.buschmais.jqassistant.plugin.json.impl.scanner.JSONFileScannerPlugin$MyErrorListener: when selecting overriding method 'void com.buschmais.jqassistant.plugin.json.impl.scanner.JSONFileScannerPlugin$MyErrorListener.syntaxError(org.antlr.v4.runtime.Recognizer, java.lang.Object, int, int, java.lang.String, org.antlr.v4.runtime.RecognitionException)' the class loader com.buschmais.jqassistant.core.runtime.api.plugin.PluginClassLoader @5b84f14 of the selected method's type com.buschmais.jqassistant.plugin.json.impl.scanner.JSONFileScannerPlugin$MyErrorListener, and the class loader 'app' for its super type org.antlr.v4.runtime.BaseErrorListener have different Class objects for the type org.antlr.v4.runtime.Recognizer used in the signature (com.buschmais.jqassistant.plugin.json.impl.scanner.JSONFileScannerPlugin$MyErrorListener is in unnamed module of loader com.buschmais.jqassistant.core.runtime.api.plugin.PluginClassLoader @5b84f14, parent loader 'app'; org.antlr.v4.runtime.BaseErrorListener is in unnamed module of loader 'app')
at com.buschmais.jqassistant.plugin.json.impl.parsing.JQAssistantJSONLexer.(JQAssistantJSONLexer.java:17)
at com.buschmais.jqassistant.plugin.json.impl.scanner.JSONFileScannerPlugin.scan(JSONFileScannerPlugin.java:87)
at com.buschmais.jqassistant.plugin.json.impl.scanner.JSONFileScannerPlugin.scan(JSONFileScannerPlugin.java:27)
at com.buschmais.jqassistant.core.scanner.impl.ScannerImpl.scan(ScannerImpl.java:125)
at com.buschmais.jqassistant.core.scanner.impl.ScannerImpl.scan(ScannerImpl.java:89)
at com.buschmais.jqassistant.core.scanner.impl.ScannerImpl.scan(ScannerImpl.java:64)
at com.buschmais.jqassistant.plugin.common.api.scanner.AbstractContainerScannerPlugin.scan(AbstractContainerScannerPlugin.java:53)
at com.buschmais.jqassistant.plugin.common.api.scanner.AbstractContainerScannerPlugin.scan(AbstractContainerScannerPlugin.java:29)
at com.buschmais.jqassistant.core.scanner.impl.ScannerImpl.scan(ScannerImpl.java:125)
at com.buschmais.jqassistant.core.scanner.impl.ScannerImpl.scan(ScannerImpl.java:89)
at com.buschmais.jqassistant.core.scanner.impl.ScannerImpl.scan(ScannerImpl.java:64)
at com.buschmais.jqassistant.plugin.common.api.scanner.AbstractZipArchiveScannerPlugin.scan(AbstractZipArchiveScannerPlugin.java:50)
at com.buschmais.jqassistant.plugin.common.api.scanner.AbstractZipArchiveScannerPlugin.scan(AbstractZipArchiveScannerPlugin.java:20)
at com.buschmais.jqassistant.core.scanner.impl.ScannerImpl.scan(ScannerImpl.java:125)
at com.buschmais.jqassistant.core.scanner.impl.ScannerImpl.scan(ScannerImpl.java:89)
at com.buschmais.jqassistant.core.scanner.impl.ScannerImpl.scan(ScannerImpl.java:64)
at com.buschmais.jqassistant.plugin.common.impl.scanner.FileScannerPlugin.scan(FileScannerPlugin.java:35)
at com.buschmais.jqassistant.plugin.common.impl.scanner.FileScannerPlugin.scan(FileScannerPlugin.java:21)
at com.buschmais.jqassistant.core.scanner.impl.ScannerImpl.scan(ScannerImpl.java:125)
at com.buschmais.jqassistant.core.scanner.impl.ScannerImpl.scan(ScannerImpl.java:85)
at com.buschmais.jqassistant.core.scanner.impl.ScannerImpl.scan(ScannerImpl.java:64)
at com.buschmais.jqassistant.commandline.task.ScanTask.scan(ScanTask.java:103)
at com.buschmais.jqassistant.commandline.task.ScanTask.lambda$scanFiles$4(ScanTask.java:93)
at java.base/java.util.Optional.ifPresent(Optional.java:183)
at com.buschmais.jqassistant.commandline.task.ScanTask.scanFiles(ScanTask.java:83)
at com.buschmais.jqassistant.commandline.task.ScanTask.lambda$run$0(ScanTask.java:61)
at java.base/java.util.Optional.ifPresentOrElse(Optional.java:201)
at com.buschmais.jqassistant.commandline.task.ScanTask.lambda$run$2(ScanTask.java:60)
at com.buschmais.jqassistant.commandline.task.AbstractStoreTask.withStore(AbstractStoreTask.java:52)
at com.buschmais.jqassistant.commandline.task.ScanTask.run(ScanTask.java:51)
at com.buschmais.jqassistant.commandline.Main.executeTask(Main.java:311)
at com.buschmais.jqassistant.commandline.Main.executeTasks(Main.java:270)
at com.buschmais.jqassistant.commandline.Main.interpretCommandLine(Main.java:209)
at com.buschmais.jqassistant.commandline.Main.run(Main.java:89)
at com.buschmais.jqassistant.commandline.Main.main(Main.java:70)
The scan was working before, but for whatever reason it stopped working. I have tried setting the runtime version of ANTLR 4.9.2 but still getting the error message. I did not have any runtime version of ANTLR configured till now.

This looks like an issue which we fixed in the upcoming release. Can you try with the latest milestone 2.2.0-M2)? The first RC is already around the corner.

Hey @DirkMahler, thank you for the comment. I did some tests and it is related to the   store:
embedded:
neo4j-plugins:
- group-id: org.neo4j.procedure
artifact-id: apoc
version: 4.4.0.26
which I have included in my .jassistant.yml. The interesting thing is that if I don't add the jar files which need to be scanned in the .jassistant.yml but instead pass it to the ./jqassistant/bin/jqassistant.sh scan it works. Do you have any clue what could be the problem?

This issue should be solved with https://github.com/jQAssistant/jqa-json-plugin/issues/15, coming soon in 2.3.0
